# How to join data with method invocation that return List of objects instead of array of objects in Esper EPL

Tags: esper

Is it possible to join events with static method invocations that return List or Set of Objects instead of Array of Objects in [Esper EPL](http://esper.codehaus.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per documentation the engine allows array only currently.